# How to get the surround points of a specific centre point?

Tags: java

[Image representation of what I want, I need to find get the points that surround the middle point, I have no idea how to implement such a thing. It's my first project and I am trying to build a game. The surround points represent the area of which an effect will take place.

a Damageable is an entity in-game that can get damaged.
a castArea is the intended area for the effect to take place in.
an AreaOfEffect is the type of intended area, if it is SELFTARGET then it will only apply to what entity the player is using.

the letter 'a' represents the ability the player will use.

targets is an ArrayList containing the champions aka Damageables][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qa7g1.png)

```java
if(a.getCastArea() == AreaOfEffect.SURROUND){
            Point currentLoc = getCurrentChampion().getLocation();
            targets.add((Damageable) board[(int) currentLoc.getX()][(int) (currentLoc.getY()+1)]);
            targets.add((Damageable) board[(int) currentLoc.getX()][(int) (currentLoc.getY()-1)]);
            
            targets.add((Damageable) board[(int) currentLoc.getX()+1][(int) (currentLoc.getY())]);
            targets.add((Damageable) board[(int) currentLoc.getX()-1][(int) (currentLoc.getY())]);
            
            targets.add((Damageable) board[(int) currentLoc.getX()+1][(int) (currentLoc.getY()+1)]);
            targets.add((Damageable) board[(int) currentLoc.getX()+1][(int) (currentLoc.getY()-1)]);
            
            targets.add((Damageable) board[(int) currentLoc.getX()-1][(int) (currentLoc.getY()-1)]);
            targets.add((Damageable) board[(int) currentLoc.getX()-1][(int) (currentLoc.getY()+1)]);
            a.execute(targets);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have validated if the locations of the surround area of the centre champion are out of bounds of the game board or not, here is the code:

```java
if (a.getCastArea() == AreaOfEffect.SURROUND) {
            Point currentLoc = getCurrentChampion().getLocation();
            if(currentLoc.y + 1 < 5 && currentLoc.y + 1 > 0)
            targets.add((Damageable) board[(int) currentLoc.x][(int) (currentLoc
                    .y + 1)]);
            if(currentLoc.y - 1 > 0 && currentLoc.y - 1 < 5)
            targets.add((Damageable) board[(int) currentLoc.x][(int) (currentLoc
                    .y - 1)]);
            if(currentLoc.x + 1 > 0 && currentLoc.x + 1 < 5)
            targets.add((Damageable) board[(int) currentLoc.x + 1][(int) (currentLoc
                    .y)]);
            if(currentLoc.x - 1 > 0 && currentLoc.x - 1 < 5)
            targets.add((Damageable) board[(int) currentLoc.x - 1][(int) (currentLoc
                    .y)]);
            if((currentLoc.y + 1 < 5 && currentLoc.y + 1 > 0) && (currentLoc.x + 1 > 0 && currentLoc.x + 1 < 5))
            targets.add((Damageable) board[(int) currentLoc.x + 1][(int) (currentLoc
                    .y + 1)]);
            if((currentLoc.y - 1 < 5 && currentLoc.y - 1 > 0) && (currentLoc.x + 1 > 0 && currentLoc.x + 1 < 5))
            targets.add((Damageable) board[(int) currentLoc.x + 1][(int) (currentLoc
                    .y - 1)]);
            if((currentLoc.y - 1 < 5 && currentLoc.y - 1 > 0) && (currentLoc.x - 1 > 0 && currentLoc.x - 1 < 5))
            targets.add((Damageable) board[(int) currentLoc.x - 1][(int) (currentLoc
                    .y - 1)]);
            if((currentLoc.y + 1 < 5 && currentLoc.y + 1 > 0) && (currentLoc.x - 1 > 0 && currentLoc.x - 1 < 5))
            targets.add((Damageable) board[(int) currentLoc.x - 1][(int) (currentLoc
                    .y + 1)]);
            a.execute(targets);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're operating on some sort of grid.

I assume that this grid is stored in some kind of an array with dimensions x,y.

If all of this is true, you would find the points around the current point (the champion), by iterating through the array. The points around the champion would be as follows:

[image: Points around champion]

Comment: I provided the code now, sorry I did not know how to put code snippets. Based on your answer I guess what I have written is correct

Comment: No problem, and yes it seems that the code you wrote aligns with what I was thinking. Did you figure it out then?